# Why is my script destroying assets? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my script I instantiate obstacles (prefabs are stored at `prefabObstacles` array) at transforms position (`emptyTransforms` array). This script is attached to `gameobject` which is segment of the world. This segment is dynamically instantiated and destroyed.

```
public class ObstaclePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int obstaclesAmmount;
    public GameObject[] prefabObstacles;
    public Transform[] emptyTransforms;
    public GameObject[] obstacles;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateObstacles();
    }

    void GenerateObstacles()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Random.Range(0,obstaclesAmmount); i++)
        {
            GameObject objToSpawn = prefabObstacles[Random.Range(0, prefabObstacles.Length)];
            obstacles[i] = Instantiate(objToSpawn, (emptyTransforms[Random.Range(0, emptyTransforms.Length)].position+new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f)), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        foreach(GameObject item in obstacles)
        {
            Destroy(item);
        }
    } 
}
```

This bug is occurring:

> Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
>   If you really want to remove an asset use `DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);`
>   UnityEngine.Object:Destroy(Object)
>   ObstaclePlacer:OnDestroy() (at Assets/Scripts/ObstaclePlacer.cs:37)

It only works if obstacles array size is fixed.

Do you know how can I fix that?
If you need more details just ask me. Thanks for help!

Comment: you have `void OnDestroy()` which obviously is called when that object is Destroyed.  In the code of `void OnDestroy()` .............................. you are telling it to Destroy all the other items.  So, of course it is doing that.

Comment: @Joe Blow But why it is destroying asset instead of gameobject in the scene? Aleso it isn't doing this, and this error occurrs.

Comment: What have you assigned in `public GameObject[] obstacles`, does it include prefabs from your project assets folder?

Comment: @HappyApple I made mistake, because `obstacles` array shouldn't be public. When i changed it to private this error occurres: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ObstaclePlacer.OnDestroy ()`

Comment: Your foreach should be like this `foreach(GameObject item in obstacles) { Destroy(item); }` btw.

Comment: @GunnarB. ok fixed that

Comment: @HappyApple Actually until I don't do something like this `GameObject[] obstacles = new GameObject[2];` obstacles are not instantiated.

Comment: Is your aim to destroy all objects on a terrain segment when it is destroyed? If so, just make them a child of the terrain segment after instantiation: `obstacles[i].transform.SetParent(this.tranform);` should do that if the script is on that terrain segment. You don't need the `OnDestroy` in that case.

Comment: @GunnarB. why would `GameObject` instead of `var` make a difference? They are both the same in the foreach loop.

Comment: @GunnarB. It works, but now main problem is that until I use this `public GameObject[] obstacles;` instead of fixed size array it doesn't instantiate them at all.

Comment: Never mind it instantiates them, but doesn't makes them children of this object(at least in hierarchy)

Comment: @Gunnar B. OnDestroy is called when the MonoBehavior script is disposed more or less like an IDisposable in .Net  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html

var and GameObject are interchangeable here.

Comment: The script is on the gameobject that should be the parent? Are they getting childs of any object?

Comment: @MattRinger yes, I know that, but I didn't get his setup at first.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes it is on gameobject that should be parent

Comment: @faken You need to initialize your array before you attempt to add items to it. Attempting to access any of obstacles items prior to setting "obstacles = new GameObject[length];" will throw an exception in both  GenerateObstacles and OnDestroy.

Comment: @MattRinger Ok i understand it now. Do there isn't any way to initialise this array without fixed size?

Comment: You would need to use a different collection like a Generic List. "using System.Collections.Generic;" then you can list.Add(GameObject) once per iteration or you would need to generate your random number first, then plug it into your array definition, then use it as the max in your for loop.... I can post an example if you like.

Comment: @MattRinger Example would be really great because this seems to be a bit complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main disconnect here is understanding how arrays work in C#. You must declare the length of the array when you initialize it, this is different than other collections such as, generic lists, which allow you to dynamically grow or shrink the list as needed. There are deeper differences between various collections and arrays, which you will want to understand before you decide which is best for your application.

This example shows how to declare and initialize an instance of both an array and generic list of type GameObjects in the context of your Behavior Script, obviously you'd want to use one or the other in your actual script.

```
class ObstaclePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int obstaclesAmmount;
    public GameObject [] obstaclesArray;
    public List<GameObject> obstaclesList;

    public void Start ()
    {
        var random = new System.Random();
        //Get the desired size of your array.
        obstaclesAmmount = random.Next(0, 100);
        //Initialize an array with the size of your random number
        obstaclesArray = new GameObject [obstaclesAmmount];
        //Or use a list which allows your to dynamically add elements later.
        obstaclesList = new List<GameObject> ();

        GenerateObstacles ();
    }

    void GenerateObstacles ()
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < obstaclesAmmount; i++) {

            var gameObject = new GameObject();

            obstaclesArray[i] = gameObject;

            obstaclesList.Add(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        foreach (GameObject item in obstaclesArray) {
            //Destroy (item);
            Console.WriteLine ("Destroy (item); in obstaclesArray");
        }

        foreach (GameObject item in obstaclesList) {
            //Destroy (item);
            Console.WriteLine ("Destroy (item); in obstaclesList");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are really helpful!